# How can I set up autocompletion for \langle and \rangle?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I use Texstudio for taking notes in class, and I would really like to set up an autocompletion scheme such that typing in "\langle" would bring up "\rangle". How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: If you use autoscale delimiters, you can use `\left<` and `\right>`.

Comment: You can define a macro to produce `\langle  \rangle` and then you call it using some shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `physics` package and exploit its `expval`  (or the short `ev`) command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
$\langle x \rangle $ $\langle x^{A} \rangle$

$\expval{x}$ $\ev*{x^{A}}$  $\expval{x^{A}}$  $\ev{x^{A}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use `mathtools` package and define a macro

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ev{\langle}{\rangle}%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ev{\langle}{\rangle}%
\begin{document}
$\langle x \rangle $ $\langle x^{A} \rangle$

$\ev{x}$ $\ev{x^{A}}$  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can create a user.cwl file with the following content

```
\langle%|\rangle
```

`%|`marks the place of the cursor. Place the file in your [settings directory](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Where_are_the_settings_stored.3F) and activate it in `Options -> Completion`.

You can find [more information on the cwl format](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) in the manual. For more complex things you can use [skripting with triggers](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33).